# How to make reference to my about page in svelte

Tags: html, svelte, svelte-3

On the latest sveltekit I am trying to refer to my about page but no success.

Tried

```
{# if $page.url.pathname === '/about'}{/if}

{# if $page.route === '/about'}{/if}
```

Which is correct line?

Comment: [Latest version of SvelteKit has dedicated `+error.svelte` pages](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#error). Does that help you?

Comment: @Tholle - thanks, not really. Actually its just a random page I want to refer to. Specifically... if the page (or route) is X then show component Y.

Comment: You need to provide a little more context. Are you trying to implement this code in a page or in a component called by a page? Is your page predefined (e.g. `/pages/about/+page.svelte`) or parameter-based (e.g. `/pages/[slug]/+page.svelte`)? Your question is too vague as is.

Comment: @ThomasHennes - in the +layout.svelte file. I import a component and in the +layout.svelte file I want to say that "if the page is the "about" page" then show the component. I only do not know how to refer to this "about" page.

Comment: It should be `{#if $page.route.id === '/about'}`, [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-url-data-route).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `{#if $page.route.id === '/about'}`, for more details consult the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-url-data-route).

Worth noting that, `$page.route.id` is the *literal* directory path relative to `src/routes`.

For example, with route `src/routes/blog/[postId]/+page.svelte`, when visit `https://example.com/blog/42`, the `$page.route.id` would literally be `/blog/[postId]`, instead of `/blog/42`. If you need the value `42`, you get it from `$page.params.postId`.